# spring data mongodb @Query with exclude option

Tags: spring-data, spring-mongo

Using spring data mongo repository class, how do we declare a method to return the documents with few fields excluded? Spring data reference document shows 'include' fields mechanism but not exclude.
Code from [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/):

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>

  @Query(value="{ 'firstname' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'firstname' : 1, 'lastname' : 1}")
  List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);

}
```

I need a mechanism to specify the fields to be excluded? Is this supported for repository methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

specify the fields value as 0. Ex:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String>

  @Query(value="{ 'firstname' : ?0 }", fields="{ 'firstname' : 0}")
  List<Person> findByThePersonsFirstname(String firstname);

}
```

This will not fetch firstname property of the document and value will be null in returned java object.

Comment: how then can you tell the difference between included field that has null value vs excluded field?

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty filter criteria for `findAll` query:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    @Query(value = "{}", fields = "{ 'firstname' : 0 }")
    List<Person> findAll(Sort sort);
}
```